# Oracle: stored procedure error

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm really new to SQL and I must create a stored procedure.

My idea is that I want to type my `PaperRoll_ID` and to get the "Worker_ID". Since my `PaperRoll_ID` values in the table are from 1 to 500 and my `Worker_id` values are from 1500 to 2000, I want to make it so that `PaperRoll_ID` is equal to the `Worker_id` index, not value by index (I mean, index 1 is the first `Worker_id` I added, 2 is the second and so on till 500 (the number of workers)). `PaperRoll_ID` is located in the table `invoice_Paper` and `Worker_id` in the table `machine_operator`.

Sorry if it's hard to understand, but I lack a lot of knowledge in SQL, so it's a bit hard for me to express myself.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE name_worker(pi IN NUMBER, mi OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
    Select q.worker_ID2 INTO mi 
    from invoice_paper z,machine_operator o 
    where z.PaperRoll_ID=pi AND o.WORKER_ID2 = q.worker_ID2;
END;
```

The tables are

```
create Table invoice_paper(
PaperRoll_ID Number(10) constraint ppr_id not null,
Single_Layer Varchar(20) Default 'None in stock',
Double_Layer Varchar(20) Default 'None in stock',
Manufacturer_FactoryID Integer,
primary key(PaperRoll_ID),
Constraint pprid_invoice Foreign key (Manufacturer_FactoryID) References   Paper_Factory(Factory_ID)
 );

create table machine_operator(
Insurence_ID number(10) constraint in_numb not null,
Worker_ID2 number(10) constraint worka_id not null,
operator_name Varchar(20),
Email Varchar(30),
Primary key (Insurence_ID, Worker_ID2),
Constraint wka_id Foreign key(Worker_ID2) References worker(worker_id)
);
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help express what you want to do.

Comment: @specbk q is the alias for which table in your query?

Comment: What database object is represented by the alias `q`. It doesn't map to anything in the FROM clause. As it stands you have no join criteria between `invoice_paper` and `machine_operator`.

Comment: my mistake, the alias should be the **o** from the machine operator table

Comment: @specbk please post the structures of both the tables

Comment: i edited the answer with both of the structures

Comment: there is a ROWNUM which can give you a row number for for each and you can join on the basis of that but the ROWNUM generated is dynamic and can change. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701782/rowid-oracle-any-use-for-it

Comment: @RajatMishra - that answer relates to ROWID which is rather different from ROWNUM. Although it's moot, as neither is particularly useful as a solution to the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to make it so that PaperRoll_ID is equal to the Worker_id index, not value by index (I mean, index 1 is the first Worker_id I added, 2 is the second and so on till 500 (the number of workers)"

That's really not how relational databases work. You should enforce such a relationship with a foreign key between `invoice_paper` and `machine_operator`, probably by adding `Worker_ID2` column to `invoice_paper` **(*)**.

Beyond that it's not clear what you are trying to achieve with your procedure, so it's hard to suggest anything better. However, let's assume what you want to do is get the next free worker for assignment to `invoice_paper`.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE name_worker(mi OUT NUMBER) IS
BEGIN
     Select min(o.worker_ID2) INTO mi 
     from machine_operator o 
     where o.WORKER_ID2 not in (select p.worker_ID2 
                                from invoice_paper p)
     ;
END;
```

Kept as a procedure for ease of comparison, although this sort of thing is usually written as a FUNCTION with a return value instead.

---

**(*)** Just noticed that `machine_operator` has a compound primary key. If this is correct the foreign key would have to be `(Insurence_ID, Worker_ID2)` which is ugly. It these situations it is better to have a single column surrogate primary key and enforce the compound key with an additional unique constraint.