# Basic concept of rowid

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Can the duplicate records have same rowid? As I know that rowid are always unique for each row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ROWID (oracle) - any use for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701782/rowid-oracle-any-use-for-it)

Answer (score 0):

ROWID is a Pseudocolumn. For each row in the database, the ROWID pseudocolumn returns the address of the row. Oracle Database rowid values contain information necessary to locate a row. So it will never be same. For your reference - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes your right rowid are always unique.

The ROWID  returns the address of the row. Oracle Database rowid values contain information necessary to locate a row:

- The data object number of the object
- The data block in the datafile in which the row resides
- The position of the row in the data block (first row is 0)

Values of the ROWID pseudocolumn have the datatype ROWID or UROWI

Rowid values have several important uses:

- They are the fastest way to access a single row.
- They can show you how the rows in a table are stored.
- They are unique identifiers for rows in a table.